# How to extract keys with its values and add values to print the total in python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, key-value-store

Here I have menu of a restaurant and its price. I want to check orders and add prices and print total price for order. But I am unable to extract values of keys for specific orders. How to show orders and its price together like

malesuada : $14.00
Sorry, we don't have pizza
maecenas : $12.00

total price: $26.00

> > ```
> > menu_items = {
> >     'nulla aliquam': 15.00,
> >     'malesuada': 14.00,
> >     'feugiat ipsum': 9.00,
> >     'maecenas': 12.00,
> >     'fermentum mass': 23.00
> > }
> > ordered_items = {
> >     'maecenas',
> >     'pizza',
> >     'malesuada'
> > }
> > for item in ordered_items:
> >     if item in menu_items.keys():
> >       print(item)
> >     else:
> >       print("sorry we dont have ",item)
> > ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You don't need to use `.keys()` to check if a key exists in a dictionary
- You access the price using dictionary indexing: `dictionary[key] -> value`

```py
total = 0
for item in ordered_items:
    if item in menu_items:
        print('{} : ${:2f}'.format(item, menu_items[item]))
        total += menu_items[item]
    else:
        print('Sorry we don\'t have {}'.format(item))

print('Total price : ${:2f}'.format(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to get the menu prices of the items in `ordered_items`, please note that the structure you have created for `ordered_items` is a `set` not a dictionary.

```
menu_items = {
    'nulla aliquam': 15.00,
    'malesuada': 14.00,
    'feugiat ipsum': 9.00,
    'maecenas': 12.00,
    'fermentum mass': 23.00
}
ordered_items = {
    'maecenas',
    'pizza',
    'malesuada'
}

totalPrice = sum([v for k,v in menu_items.items() if k in ordered_items])
print(totalPrice)
```

Output:

```
26.0
```

The list comprehension is just a nicer way of doing the below for loop:

**Edit** For your specification of printing of each item in the order.

```
total_price = 0 
for item in ordered_items:
    if item in menu_items:
        print(f"{item} : ${menu_items[item]} ")
        total_price += menu_items[item]
    else:
        print(f"Sorry, we don't have {item}")
print(f'Total : ${total_price}')
```

Output:

maecenas : $12.0

Sorry, we don't have pizza

malesuada : $14.0

Total : $26.0

To print all this on one line, append each statement to one string on each loop and print this at the end:

```
total_price = 0 
printString = ''
for item in ordered_items:
    if item in menu_items:
        printString += f"{item} : ${menu_items[item]} "
#        print(f"{item} : ${menu_items[item]} ")
        total_price += menu_items[item]
    else:
#        print(f"Sorry, we don't have {item}")
        printString += f"Sorry, we don't have {item} "
#print(f'Total : ${total_price}')
printString +=  f"Total : ${total_price} "

print(printString)
```

Output:

maecenas : $12.0 Sorry, we don't have pizza malesuada : $14.0 Total : $26.0

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for me. Thank you but how can I show ordered item and its price together in the same line?
Like this:  
malesuada : $14.00  
Sorry, we don't have pizza  
maecenas : $12.00

Comment: @Deep_gtm77 sure, I've edited my answer to include that.